# Laravel date time condition not working properly

Tags: laravel

I have two columns in my offer table as follow, I want to fetch those offer's record which is currently active:

| offer_start_date | offer_end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 24-10-2022 10:57:00 | 24-10-2023 10:57:00 |

Below is my query date condition working fine but time is giving problems:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$today = $now->toDateString();
$currentTime = $now->toTimeString();
$offers_data = Offer::whereRaw("offer_status=2 and offer_type=1 and is_special_offer=3")
->whereDate('offer_start_date','<=',$today)
->whereTime('offer_start_date','<=',$currentTime)
->whereDate('offer_end_date','>=',$today)
->whereTime('offer_end_date','>=',$currentTime)    
->limit(10)      
->get();
```

What would be the reason?

[image: added screenshot of records]

Comment: Maybe it depends on the timezone?

Comment: Perhaps try to parse the dates via carbon `Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y h:m','24-10-2022 10:57);` within a function and use `Carbon::now()->between($startDate,$endDate);`. This way we are explicitly using the same metric to compare with

Comment: are those fields timestamps or datetimes? I find it odd there are no seconds in your example. If the fields are stored as varchar, then some additional date casting could be needed

Comment: @IGP it's stored as datetime

Answer (score 2):

Using `whereDate` and `whereTime` together is likely not working the way you think it is.

Instead, try just using `where()` and Laravel will work it out for you.

```
$now = Carbon::now();

$offers_data = Offer::whereRaw("offer_status=2 and offer_type=1 and is_special_offer=3")
    ->where('offer_start_date', '<=', $now)
    ->where('offer_end_date', '>=', $now)    
    ->limit(10)      
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, Valid point I'm checking it